# the loop always terminates or just goes on forever without the possibilty to break

Tags: sqlite

```
user_input5 = input("If you want to add your wardrobe press Y if not press N")
if user_input5 == "y" or "Y":
while user_input7 == "y":
user_input6 = input("What to you want to add?")
if user_input6 == "socks":
conn = sqlite3.connect('allclothes.db')
c = conn.cursor()
user_input2 = input("How many?")
user_input3 = input("In what color?")
user_input4 = input("What type is it?")
statement2 = ("INSERT INTO socks VALUES (?,?,?)")
c.execute(statement2, (user_input2, user_input3, user_input4))
conn.commit()
```

user_input7 = input("Do you want to add more?(y/n)\n")
if user_input7 == "n" or "N":
break
if user_input5 == "n" or "N":
print("What else do you wanna do?")

Comment: the text outside the code is what i want to do

Comment: Please, could you correctly indent your code? It looks like Python, which syntactically needs correct indentation, otherwise the code is meaningless. Also you should rename your variables, their purpose should be clearly brought out by their names, and that's not the case currently. Also you should retag the question: add the correct version of Python, and remove SQLite, which though involved in your code, is not relevant to your problem.

Comment: Also, I *suspect* that your problem might arise from the fact that you use the variable `user_input7` before it is given a value (in the condition for the `while` loop). I may be wrong though.